# Как сделать одноразовую команду в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telegram

Мне нужно, чтобы телеграм бот не реагировал на повторные команды (для тех, кто любит баловаться).
Чтобы команда '/start' была одноразовой.
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    if str(message.chat.id) in open('test.txt', 'r').read():
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'больше нельзя')
    else:
        open('test.txt', 'a').write(str(message.chat.id) + '\n')
```

Comment: Прощай производительность...

Comment: Предложите свой вариант

Comment: Например, использовать БД. Или как-то структурировать бинарный файл, чтобы не читать его целиком для каждого сообщения. А вообще, какого типа этот id? Если int32, то можно выделить 4 ГБ на файл с битовыми флагами. Хотя сильно сомневаюсь, что количество чатов лезет в int32.

Comment: Запись в текстовый файл лишь пример, который можно использовать для дальнейшей реализации.

Comment: В этом боте нет БД. Это скорее тестовое задание чем реальный бот

Answer (score -1):

**Пример на JS**

Можете создать внешнюю переменную, в которой будете хранить последнее сообщение. При каждом последующем сообщении - можно проверять совпадают ли значения текущего сообщения и прошлого.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form')
const input = document.querySelector('input')

let prev = '';
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (prev === input.value) {
    console.log('Не балуйся')
    return;
  }
  prev = input.value
  console.log(input.value)
})
```

```html
<form><input></form>
```

Comment: Однопользовательский бот...